# Thymleaf - setting the value of a date picker in a Java spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, datetime, thymeleaf

I am trying to learn Spring Boot and Thymleaf by developing the Pet Clinic Application. I have some functionality where the user can select to edit an existing pet. One of the fields is the pets date of birth, I want to set this field to the value currently held in the database (but then allow the user to change it). I can retrieve the value from the database and get it to by controller and if I inspect the element in the webpage I can see the value  but I cannot get it to display

My Thyleaf Template is

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping("pet/edit/{id}")
public String editPet(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){



    model.addAttribute("pet", petService.findById(id));

    model.addAttribute("ownerDetails", ownerService.findAllList());

    model.addAttribute("petTypeDetails", petTypeService.findAllList());



    return "petForm";
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use databinding ? https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#handling-the-command-object

Comment: Can you try using ${dateofB} instead of the one with two parenthesis? And also try exploring data binding with Thymeleaf with spring boot

Comment: Hi I tried databinding and whilst I got it to work perfectly for all fields I could not get it to work with dates I will have another go and repost

Comment: hi - thanks for your help. I have made the changes that you suggested (see above edited question) and although I can see the correct value when I inspect the element on the webpage, the actual date picker is not updating. Can you advise ? thanks in advance

Comment: Hi - I got this to work eventually. It was quite simple but took me ages to work out. Used binding and changed the template to be     <input th:type="date" th:value="*{#dates.format(dateOfBirth, 'YYYY-MM-dd')}"  />